# print range, if number is missing

Tags: java, arrays, list, algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of number which is sorted and want to print the continuous numbers range and if any number is missing in the series, we will start a new range.
Note: There are possibility that multiple numbers are missing in the series continuously.
example:

```
Input:
list = {301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 307, 308, 310, 312, 318, 319, 322, 390}
Output: range
301 - 305 //306 is missing so it breaks and new range starts
307 - 308 //309 is missing so breaks
310  // 311 is missing so breaks
312  // 313, 314, 315, 316, 317 are missing break (1 or more number can be missed)
318 - 319
322
390
```

My Logic:

```
int count = list.get(0);
        String output = list.get(0) + "-";
        for(int n: list){
            if(count++ != n){
                output = output+(count-2);
                System.out.println(output);
                output = n+"-";
                count++;
            }
        }
```

It's failing, if there are more then 2 numbers is missing in between.

Comment: From your statement it's not obvious what represents a range and what criteria you use to identify which number to check for belonging to a range. Please state your problem on a more specific way by giving an example base case. There are potentially many numbers that are in not ranges, if a number to be checked is identified by a single-number gap between numbers, then please articulate the sequence is sorted and gaps are identified by missing numbers, explain how many numbers can be missing. They may be missing in different ranges in the same time. Your problem statement is too ambiguous.

Comment: Thank @dmitryro, have updated the question, please let me know if still there is any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use two `int`s to track the beginning and end of each range. Going over the list, as long as the next number is the following number of the end, it becomes the new end. If it isn't, you have a new range at hand:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = {301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 307, 308, 310, 312, 318, 319, 322, 390};

    int start = list[0];
    int end = list[1];
    for (int i = 2; i < list.length; ++i) {
        if (end + 1 == list[i]) {
            end++;
        } else {
            printRange(start, end);
            start = list[i];
            end = list[i];
        }
    }
    printRange(start, end);
}

private static void printRange(int start, int end) {
    if (start != end) {
        System.out.println(start + " - " + end);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(start);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using `count` and make only comparison with the last value. Pseudocode:

```
start = 0
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
   if ((i==n) || (list[i]!=list[i-1]+1)) {
       output interval  list[start] - list[i-1] 
                           //omit the second if i-1==start   
       start = i  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple logic in python -

```
list = [301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 307, 308, 310, 312, 318, 319, 322, 390]

def printRange(list):
    n = len(list)
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        flag = False
        j = i
        k = 0
        # Assuming the sequence is, difference between each number is 1
        while j + 1 < n and list[j] + 1 == list[j + 1]:
            j += 1
            k += 1
            flag = True
        if flag:
            print('{} - {}'.format(list[i], list[j]))
            i += k + 1
        else:
            print(list[i])
            i += 1

printRange(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

We use double pointers to determine whether the sequence is continuous.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 307, 308, 310, 312, 318, 319, 322, 390};
        printRange(arr);
    }
    
    private static void printRange(int[] arr) {
        int pre = arr[0];
        int start = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            while (i < arr.length - 1 && arr[i] == pre + 1) {
                pre = arr[i];
                i++;
            }
            
            // deal with last number
            if (i == arr.length - 1) {
                if (arr[i] == pre + 1) {
                    System.out.println(start + " - " + arr[i]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(start);
                    System.out.println(arr[i]);
                }
                break;
            }
            
            if (pre != start) {
                System.out.println(start + " - " + pre);
            } else {
                System.out.println(start);
            }
            pre = arr[i];
            start = arr[i];
        }
    }
```